# Any chance you can add to prototype on an instance rather than a class?

Tags: javascript

Are you forced to merge?

I can think of a way by always creating a wrapper "class" that gets to prototype an existing object but not really the same.

What options do we have to **"include"** an object onto another instance besides merging / copying ?

Comment: If you don't care about the existing prototype of your target object, you can replace it with your "parent" object using `Object.setPrototypeOf()`. But I'd personally look for other solutions before doing that.

Comment: @slappy interesting method. i can see a way of how things can be rescambled using that method. maybe create a temporary function. set prototype to target prototype and desired prototype ( possible, no? ) and then assign that function prototype to the instance using this method. question is if you do newFunction.prototype = target.prototype; newFunction.prototype = desiredPrototype; and then Object.setPrototypeOf(target, newFunction.prototype) ? Would  that work? The double assignment of newFunction.prototype will include both, no?

Comment: You wouldn't change the function prototypes (assuming you're talking about the constructor functions). That wouldn't affect any existing instances. The constructors are just a means of associating a new object with the function's prototype. After that, the new object only knows about the prototype it was given; it knows nothing of the constructor function itself.